# Q: How to set up a mix of public and protected routes? (React Router)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm currently working on a project where I have to set up some (in my opinion) complex routing with **React Router**. I only started using it a week ago and at this point I'm overwhelmed, as I'm not sure how to get this done.

What I would like to have is a working skeleton to work with, where I can implement the actual logic of making API calls to get user data and so on. Hence the dummy authentication.

Optional Info: I will be using **Material UI** to design the app.

https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-haze-1ug25?file=/src/App.js

---

## 1. Structure

1. `StartContent` (only available when logged out)

   - `LogIn` (needs to show first)
   - `SignUp`
   - `ForgotPassword`
2. `MainContent` (only available when logged in, links are inside sidebar)

   - `Overview` (needs to show first)
   - `Cashbacks`
   - `BankNew`
   - `BankExisting`
   - `Transactions`
   - `Settings`
   - `FAQ`
   - `LogOutButton`
3. `FooterContent` (always available but only when selected, links are inside `Footer` component)

   - `Imprint`
   - `TermsAndConditions`
   - `PrivacyPolicy`

---

## 2. User Flow

1. User needs to log in, `LogIn` component is the first thing that shows. It's a child component of `StartContent`, which contains `LogIn`, `SignUp`and `ForgotPassword`. User is able to navigate between the three components.
2. After logging in, `StartContent` is not available anymore and `Navigation`and `MainContent` will show. `Navigation` will contain another component called `SideDrawer`, which will open the sidebar so the user can select and navigate. For simplicity I altered the example from **React Router**.
3. When logging out, only the content of `StartContent` will be available again and `LogIn` will show first.
4. The `Footer`component must always be available, no matter if logged in or not. Through it, the user can access `FooterContent`.

---

## 3. Questions

At the moment I can only access `PrivateRoute` by clicking on the respective link. How do I set up the routing to show `LogIn` first, when not logged in? I don't want to click on this link to get there and would like to get rid of it.

After logging in, the sidebar shows up and the log out button is working fine, but as soon as I select one of `MainContent`s routes, the sidebar disappears and no content is shown. How do I fix this? On it's own the sidebar is working fine.

`Footer` component should always be available. Through it you can access the children of `FooterContent`. How do I set it up so it works no matter if I'm logged in or out?

---

Thank you very much for reading and taking the time to help me, I really appreciate it!

If you need any more info or if something is not clear, please let me know. I know it's a lot...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need a complete routing structure.
Here is an idea/example of it:

main route file

```
return (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
    <PublicRoute component={Login} path="/login" exact />
    <PublicRoute  component={SignUp} path="/signup" exact />
    <PublicRoute component={ForgotPassword} path="/forgot-password" exact />
    <PrivateRoute component={Overview} path="/overview" exact />
    <PrivateRoute component={Cashbacks} path="/cashbacks" exact />
    <PrivateRoute component={BankNew} path="/bank-new" exact />
    <PrivateRoute component={BankExisting} path="/bank-existing" exact />
    <PrivateRoute component={Transactions} path="/transactions" exact />
    <PrivateRoute component={Settings} path="/settings" exact />
    <PrivateRoute component={FAQ} path="/faq" exact />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

publicRoute

```
const PublicRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            // if user is already logged in, then redirect to the dashboard/overview page
            isLogin()?
                <Redirect to="/overview" />
            : <Component {...props} />
        )} />
    );
};
```

privateRoute

```
const PrivateRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    return (
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            // if user has not logged in then redirect him to /login page
            isLogin() ?
                <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to="/login" />
        )} />
    );
};
```

This may not be exactly what you have asked but will give you an idea about creating the routing structure.